# Om not reflecting changes even after swap! app-state

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable, om

Using Light Table, how do I tell Om to re-render the DOM after eval'ing a modified Om function?

Forcing a swap! on the main state atom has no effect:
`(swap! app-state identity)`

Cycling routes explicitly with `(swap! app-state assoc :current-page :about)` and back to home with `(swap! app-state assoc :current-page :home)`, reflect changes to the home page.

My browser is connected to Light Table and I can trigger alerts with, e.g. `(js/alert "hi")`

Calling the root again also triggers a render:

```
(root app app-state
      {:target (. js/document
                  (getElementById "site"))})
```

Why doesn't Om trigger a render on app-state atom `swap!`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `swap!` instead of `om/transact!`?

Comment: I'm an Om noob. I didn't know I should be a using `om/transact!`.

Answer (score 2):

In Om, you should modify your application state atom with `om/update!` and `om/transact!`.